# in Git Bash only, node is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, node.js, git-bash

node and git are installed in the same dir, git recognizes both node and npm, but when I run this script in git bash it throws this error. I've tested running in PS and that works just fine.  Any ideas?

[looks like it's all installed and recognized?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NtX9.png)

Comment: This is normally a PATH issue, that is an environment variable (also known as parameter) which tells your shell where it looks for the utility "node" (in your case) by going through all directories from front to back (the PATH can contain multiple directories). Try `man bash | grep '^\s\+PATH' -A 2` (depending on display width, take a number greater than two to read the whole paragraph) it *should* work under git bash (double cross fingers), this is an excerpt from the manual page of the BASH shell regarding it. The "node" command needs to be in any of these directories.

Comment: See as well: [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26047/9340)

Comment: @hakre no 'man' in git bash :(

Comment: oh, ah now I remember, this is why when you use the `--help` on git commands it opens the HTML help. It was some time ago I was using Windows, but I always liked the git bash there. As an alternative the manpages are also available online, e.g. here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables - the PATH variable is very typical and central in a shell to find the executeables. do you know the full path (absolute path) to the "node" command on your system?

Answer (score 0):

use mklink to ref node to git bin folder

```
mklink C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin\node.exe  C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
```